# Controlling AI in space recreating humans

Tags: story-identification, space, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to find the name of a sci-fi story in which two competing orbiting AI send down AI probes to the surface of the earth and end up putting those probe AI's into bodies of frozen humans so that those space based AI can be given new instructions.

Comment: Definitely a dupe....

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113812/ais-launch-colony-mission-to-save-humanity-without-telling-the-humans?

Comment: @Valorum - I don't think so, but I *have* seen this before, possibly on this website.

Comment: By the way, I got rid of the [tag:frozen] tag. ;) It's actually for the Disney film of the same name.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Thought it would explain Anna and Elsa's wooden acting skills...

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything close to this in my searches.  I read it as a kid 40+ years ago but can't remember any more details or who the author was.

Comment: Do the AIs repopulate Earth?

Comment: Could it be [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55023/looking-for-a-story-about-a-post-apocalyptic-earth-where-an-ai-learns-about-huma)?

Comment: Awesome, yes that is the story!

Roger Zelazny. For a Breath I Tarry

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help. Since you have confirmed that this is the right answer, we can close the question as duplicate now.

Comment: @Adamant But the previous one wasn't confirmed ;-)